# Should I perform a disjunctive syllogism directly on three expressions simultaneously?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider

$$\begin{align*}
&1.\quad \lnot R \lor \lnot T \lor U\\
&2.\quad R\\
&3.\quad T
\end{align*}$$

It seems clear that you can end up with this:
$$4.\quad U$$

Now then, number $4$ was made by using disjunctive syllogism on **three** statements at the same time. Is that alright (for, say, a formal proof in a test), or am I supposed to do it "slower" and only do inferences with two statements at a time?

Another title for this question **could** have been: Is it alright to do inferences with more than two statements simultaneously? But, apparently, the **destructive dilemma** inference rule actually uses three statements anyway, so I guess I should keep this to just disjunctive syllogisms.

Comment: It would be perfectly clear for me, but I know some who pay strict attention to such details and want students to labor through all the rules one by one (especially freshmen). The fact is that it is easier to grade, e.g. with more verbose solution, if you make the mistake in the middle, there would be the next derivation to fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\quad\quad \quad \;\;\;\;\;\;1. \quad \lnot R \lor \lnot T \lor U$$
$$2.\quad R$$
$$3. \quad T$$
$$4. \quad  U $$

Given the three premises $(1), (2), (3)$, yes indeed, $(4)$ is true. But assuming your task is to *prove* that $U$ follows from the first three premises: why *wouldn't* you add the intermediate step $(3.5)$, citing the premises and/or derivations used?:

$$(3.5)\; \lnot T \lor U\tag{ (1) (2) Disjunctive Syllogism}$$
$$(4)\; U \tag{ (3), (3.5) Disjunctive Syllogism}$$

---

You may want to speak to your instructor about how much detail to show. The disjunctive syllogism is typically taught as:

$$p \lor q$$
$$\lnot p$$
$$\therefore q$$

so you may also need to add $\lnot\lnot R$ from $(2)$, and $\lnot\lnot T$ from $(3)$, and then move to what I've numbered as $(3.5), (4)$, citing the respective premises to which double negation applies.

Again, it depends on your instructor, how explicit you need to be in your proofs.

Comment: The numbering can give away to ambiguity since the number '4' is used in two steps it may be confusing (even though there is parenthesis)

Comment: I was just editing! Thanks, that's what I just corrected!

Answer (score 2):

Given:

$$1. ¬R∨¬T∨U$$
$$2. R$$ 
$$3. T$$ 
$$4. U$$

Using parentheses:

$$1. ¬R∨(¬T∨U)$$

Disjunctive syllogism is:
$$p∨q$$
$$¬p$$
$$∴q$$

Next step:

$$1. ¬R∨(¬T∨U)$$
$$2. R$$ 
$$3. T$$ 
$$4. U$$ 
$$5.  (¬T∨U) //justification: 1,2 DS $$
$$6.  U //justification: 3,5 DS $$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the main question:

> Is it alright to do inferences with more than two statements simultaneously?

The only inference rules one can formally use are those that have been formally defined.

Here is how the proof would look in a Fitch-style proof checker using disjunctive syllogism (DS) twice where I was forced to enter well-formed formulas and follow the inference rules:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/